# background-image not being displayed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to set the background-image on `<div class="jumbotron">` which for some reason seems impossible. The image is not being displayed.

If I set the background-image on body with the same code, I get the background-image but not in the jumbotron.

css:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("/Img/banner.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: #808080;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p class="lead">More text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove: `background: #808080;` in the .jumbotron class

Comment: thanks, but i have never had to do that before, so that if theres something wrong with the pic i just get the color i want as bg... wierd

Comment: did you double check the path of the image, or even better if you know how to use inspect element on your browser you can definitely fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're setting the `background-image` property **first** and then overriding it with the `background` property.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> The background CSS shorthand property assigns explicit given values
>   and sets missing properties to their initial values.

That last bit is important - *and sets missing properties to their initial values*.

The initial value for the `background-image` property is `none`.

So, by setting the `background-image` and then setting the `background` with only the `color` value it is essentially clearing the `background-image`, setting it back to `none`.

Try the following, it will fallback to your background color if the image isn't found or does not load correctly.

```
background: url("/img/banner.jpg") #808080 no-repeat;
```

Your rule definition would then become

```
 .jumbotron {
     background: url("/img/banner.jpg") #808080 no-repeat;
     color: #ffffff;
     width: 80%;
     max-height: 400px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0;
 }
```

---

Here are a two examples to show how it works, one with a working image url and one without that reverts to your fallback color.

**Example with working image url**

```css
.jumbotron {
     background: url("https://placehold.it/650x175?text=BANNER HERE") #808080 no-repeat;
     color: #ffffff;
     width: 80%;
     max-height: 400px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p class="lead">More text</p>
</div>
```

**Example with a broken image url reverting to fallback color**

```css
.jumbotron {
     background: url("https://broken.url/noimagehere.jpg") #808080 no-repeat;
     color: #ffffff;
     width: 80%;
     max-height: 400px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p class="lead">More text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmn, try to open your browser tools and check this jumbotron. You can try to use Mozilla for it, they have really nice tools and you can very easy manipulate CSS styles.

You can also try something like this:

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #000">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p class="lead">More text</p>
</div>
```